# Initializer element is not a compile-time constant using C

Tags: c, initialization, global-variables, constant-expression, storage-duration

a.h

```
list* FunctionNamesCreate();
list* const FunctionNames = FunctionNamesCreate();
```

a.c

```
list* FunctionCreate() {
    list* FunctionNames = listCreate(sizeof(char*));
    listPushHead(FunctionNames,"s");
    return FunctionNames;
}
```

`list` is simple `void*` linked list structure

When I want to create `FunctionNames` global variable the code editor give me the following error:  `a.h:8:29: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant`. If I do not use the `const` before
`FunctionNames` the the code editor give me the same error.

Comment: There's limits on what you can create as a global `const`.

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Your C code is against the rules of C.

Comment: You can only call a function from inside another function.

Comment: C is not C++, no.

Comment: if you show full code what you are doing with `FunctionCreate` and `listPushHead`, i can improve answer

Comment: In practice, runtime initialization should happen early in `main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declaration

```
list* const FunctionNames = FunctionNamesCreate();
```

is a file scope declaration with static storage duration that may be initialized by a constant compile-time expression.

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 4 All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
> or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
> literals.

This expression

```
FunctionNamesCreate()
```

is not a compile-time constant expression. The function call evaluates at run-time.

From the C Standard (6.6 Constant expressions)

> 3 **Constant expressions shall not contain** assignment, increment,
> decrement, **function-call**, or comma operators, except when they are
> contained within a subexpression that is not evaluated.

There is no need to declare the pointer at a file scope. It is a bad approach moreover when you placed a pointer definition with external linkage in a header. Declare the pointer for example in main.

Answer (score 1):

In C language code can be only executed inside the functions. In the global scope only constant expressions can be used to initialize the variables.

Static storage objects can be only initialized using constant expressions.